# Vue.js: Disabling a button on parent component based on state of child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have read the documentation on parent and child communication. I understand that children communicate to the parent by emitting events and that the parent component passes down props to the child component.

I am struggling to apply this principle to my project:

I have a `Survey` component that contains multiple pages. I am using vswipe to implement a slider for the pages (https://github.com/wangdahoo/vswipe)
Each `<swipe-item>` contains a `QuestionGroup` component which in turn contains multiple `Questions`.

Some of these questions are required.

How do I disable/enable the vswipe next and previous buttons (that are contained in the parent `Survey` component) based on the state of the `questions` in the currently displayed `QuestionGroup` component?

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit painful. You may consider using [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) for a more elegant pattern.

By the way, you said everything in your question. Just use events to communicate from child to parent.

Here is one way:

```js
Vue.component('Question', {
  template: `<div>
        {{ name }}:
        <input type="text" 
          @input="toogleFilled($event.target.value)">
        </input>
    </div>`,
  props: ['name'],
  methods: {
    toogleFilled(inputValue) {
      // Emit name of the component and true if input is filled...
      this.$emit('filled', this.name, !!inputValue.length);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('QuestionGroup', {
  template: `<div>
        <template v-for="(q, key) in questions">
          <question :name="key" @filled="toogleReady">
          </question>
        </template>
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      // Each key will be the name of the question 
      // Each value will be if it's filled or not
      questions: {
        'Question1': false,
        'Question2': false
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toogleReady(name, filled) {
      this.questions[name] = filled;

      // Check if each question is filled, if yes, emit true
      if (filled && Object.values(this.questions).every(q => q)) {
        this.$emit('readyToSwipe', true);
      } else {
        this.$emit('readyToSwipe', false);
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('Survey', {
  template: `<div>
     <button :disabled="isDisabled">I'm doing nothing</button>
        <question-group @readyToSwipe="toogleDisabled"></question-group>
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      isDisabled: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toogleDisabled(ready) {
      // Disable the button if the question-group is not ready
      this.isDisabled = !ready;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <survey></survey>
</div>
```

Comment: This would not work if the child component is immutable (i.e. a 3rd party node_module of some kind).